# KeyError on column appears only in when I assign column value, all other cells can use column except this assigned cell

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

**Problem**

Odd, when I run this in Jupyter Notebook new cells it works, but inside my full Jupyter Notebook I never drop the column but the data frame somehow has this column missing, hence error below. The only logic between # SETUP and # ASSIGN is code that processes missing values. When I step through all cells in Jupyter the SalePrice column is available to use, but once it hits the cell in Jupyter ASSIGN code cell (below) then the KeyError is raised.

**Data**

**ASSIGN Code Issue**

Here, train_data['SalePrice'] IS missing SalePrice column

```
# ASSIGN
train_data.replace(np.nan, 0)
Y = train_data['SalePrice']
X = train_data.drop(['Id'], axis=1)
...
KeyError...
...
```

**Setup data frame**

Here train_data HAS SalePrice.

```
# SETUP
import pandas as pd
train_data = pd.read_csv("../data/train.csv")
test_data = pd.read_csv("../data/test.csv")
Y = train_data['SalePrice']
```

Y resolved to this data

```
0       208500
1       181500
2       223500
3       140000
4       250000
         ...  
1455    175000
1456    210000
1457    266500
1458    142125
1459    147500
Name: SalePrice, Length: 1460, dtype: int64
```

**Error KeyError**

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py:3629, in Index.get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3628 try:
-> 3629     return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3630 except KeyError as err:

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/_libs/index.pyx:136, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/_libs/index.pyx:163, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

File pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi:5198, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

File pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi:5206, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'SalePrice'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[88], line 2
      1 train_data.replace(np.nan, 0)
----> 2 Y = train_data['SalePrice']
      3 X = train_data.drop(['Id'], axis=1)

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py:3505, in DataFrame.__getitem__(self, key)
   3503 if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   3504     return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 3505 indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   3506 if is_integer(indexer):
   3507     indexer = [indexer]

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py:3631, in Index.get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3629     return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3630 except KeyError as err:
-> 3631     raise KeyError(key) from err
   3632 except TypeError:
   3633     # If we have a listlike key, _check_indexing_error will raise
   3634     #  InvalidIndexError. Otherwise we fall through and re-raise
   3635     #  the TypeError.
   3636     self._check_indexing_error(key)

KeyError: 'SalePrice'
```

Comment: I believe somewhere in your code it mustve gotten dropped. Why dont you see the value of `train_data` at each step and see at which point the column is missing?

Comment: train_data.replace(np.nan, 0),  Not a good solution, nan values need special handling. Find the columns nan and and process them separately, then use Y.

Comment: Yes, I know replace(np.nan, 0) is not good, I was trying to experiment on last minute process to see if I was able to get Y column showing up...

Comment: It appear that this index alignment code removes the SalePrice column.

Comment: col_train = train_data.columns
for index in col_train:
    if index in col_test:
        pass
    else:
        del train_data[index]